# How to specify correct dialog size in XML layout file for Android dialog?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, performance

I have created an android dialog using an XML layout file like so:

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enabledialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Define message keys and setup");

        Switch locationSwitch = (Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.locationSwitch);
        Switch blareSwitch = (Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.blareSwitch);

        final EditText locationEdit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.locationEdit);
        final EditText blareEdit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.blareEdit);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        dialog.show();

        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

However, my XML file's contents only take up half of the screen, so when I display the dialog, I am showing extra space, which doesn't look nice:

### HERE IS A SKETCH OF HOW THE DIALOG LOOKS (R.layout.enabledialog):

[image]

How do I trim this extra space? In android studio, the layout editor assumes the XML file is to take up the whole screen, but really, I only want a small popup window.

Thanks,

Ruchir

---

**EDIT: Here is my layout resource file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1dd1e9">


    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Blah"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blareSwitch"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Blah"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blareSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blareEdit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout resource file. You might also wish to change `MATCH_PARENT` to `WRAP_CONTENT` in your Java code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited :)

Comment: @CommonsWare I actually had it at `MATCH_PARENT` because when it was `WRAP_CONTENT`, the content was overlapping and not fitting properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `fill_parent` to `wrap_content` in your root `RelativeLayout`, as well as changing `MATCH_PARENT` to `WRAP_CONTENT` in your Java code (or get rid of the whole `setAttributes()` bit).

> I actually had it at MATCH_PARENT because when it was WRAP_CONTENT, the content was overlapping and not fitting properly

Then that's a separate problem that you would need to fix. Start by getting the dialog size to be roughly what you want. Then, use some inspection tool (the new one in AS 2.2, Hierarchy View, `uiautomatorviewer`, etc.) to start figuring out how to fix your layout to avoid your overlaps.

Comment: Okay, I have changed all the `MATCH_PARENT`'S to `WRAP_CONTENT`'s, and the overlapping is continuing. How do I get/use those inspection tools you talked about? Thanks

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: `uiautomatorviewer` is a command-line tool in your SDK. Hierarchy View is in the Android Device Monitor (available from Tools > Android in the Android Studio main menu). Both are covered in the docs, at least lightly. Basically, they give you a look at the actual content of your UI, loaded from the device, so you can visualize the rules as they are actually being applied.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing yout layout parameters height to:

`lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;`

Answer (score 2):

I usually set the `LayoutParams` programmatically. I think you can try `DialogFragment` with below code in `onResume`:

```
/**
 * Setup position of dialog 
 */
protected void setupDialogPosition() {
    // setup the dialog
    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    p.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    p.y = 0;
    // change height of dailog
    if (mHeight == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
        p.height = mScreenHeight - p.y;
        if (isStatusBarVisible()) {
            p.height -= getStatusBarHeight();
        }
        } else {
        p.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
    getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(mGravity);
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert directly from resource value:

```
int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);
int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_height);        
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Now `match_parent` in your layout for the dialog:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In your Relative Layout specify the layout_height and layout_width , and do not set it to fill_parent .
Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customdia_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="hello"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/custdia_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customdia_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create custom Dialog as follows

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    }
}
```

look at the override method onAttachedToWindow(), here is your trick.this method gets called before onCreate() method. so you can override windows property(width and height) before your dialog gets created.

call this Dialog from your Activity as follows

```
new MyDialog(ActivityContext).show();
```

also do some modification in dialog.xml file as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Blah"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

edit layout file if you want any extra customization

Answer (score 1):

change the Main RelativeLayout size as per requirement in xml file. Specify the Height what you need like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#1dd1e9">

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/locationSwitch"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Blah"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locationSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/locationSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:singleLine = "true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/blareSwitch"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Blah"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blareSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/blareEdit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:singleLine = "true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

change the Height and width as per Requirements and its not required to setAttributes(lp); in Java . 
if you are setting make sure that you consider the xml RelativeLayout Height and Width

Comment: How do I know which height?

Comment: plz check the code in parent RelativeLaout i have given Height as 100dp
use that and change as per requirement.

Comment: change the parent layout height check the code and do trail and error..